# How can I make fontawesome icons appear in the navbar like in the react-bootstrap documentation?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make some icons appear like in the documentation here: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/navbar/ however I can not seem to get the same result:

```html
<Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Link className="text-white" target="_blank" href="#">
    <OverlayTrigger
      placement="bottom"
      overlay={
        <Tooltip id={"tooltip-bottom"}>
          GitHub
      </Tooltip>
      }
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} />
    </OverlayTrigger>
  </Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
```

Does anyone know how to make the icons appear like in the documentation?

Comment: In the documentation you linked to I don't see that a <FontAwesomeIcon /> component is being used. Bootstrap doesn’t include an icon library by default, as is stated in their official documentation. You can use font awesome by importing it and give your menu the classNames of fa and fa-github along with the class thats currently there, text-white

Comment: Sorry but could you give a example? I tried to remove the fontawesomeicon and add the icon in the classname as you said but then I got a error saying that it's expecting a child component

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the packages `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` and `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`.

Then you can import them in your component like so.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faDatabase } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

You can use them in your project like this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faDatabase} />
```

If you go in your `node_modules/@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons` directory you will see a bunch of Typescript (.ts) files. These files represent the icons.

I could not find the Git icon in there so that might be the reason it's not showing up. However, the Git icon is available in the @fortawesome/fontawesome-free package as an SVG. The downside is that I don't think you can use the SVG icon with the  component. This means that you may need to find another workaround for that.

Comment: Sorry I do see the icon, the code is working but it does not appear like in the documentation, instead I get a smaller icon and no hover effect, I was wondering if there was a way to do it without custom css because in the docs I don't see custom css for that being used